# Android "ListView" items text overlapping and cut off

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, user-interface

I'm trying to add buttons to a ListView of items so that a User can add specials to their "Favorites" by clicking a button/checkbox. Before adding this functionality, the layout of the list looked fine.

Here is the "before" image: [image: Good Layout]

Here is the "before" java code:

```
ArrayList<Special> specials = specialda.getAllSpecialsByDay(selectedDay);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<Special> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Special>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, specials);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, after changing the Java code to this:

```
ArrayList<Special> specials = specialda.getAllSpecialsByDay(selectedDay);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<Special> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Special>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, specials);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I end up with this distorted view:

[image: After image]

Here is the xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.yourfullname.flashcards.laxspecials.DisplaySpecials"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_specials">

    <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Any tips on what I am doing wrong or need to change?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is up display_specials_button.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dublicate source of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` performing necessary changes:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd" />
```

The difference is, that now you provide `android:minHeight` and `android:layout_height` in different way.

Comment: Where do I place this xml?

Comment: Create a layout and pass to your adapter: `new ArrayAdapter<Special>(this, R.layout.your_new_layout, specials);`

Comment: ok i'm getting an "Session 'app': error installing APK" error upon running

Comment: Post your logcat and newly created layout file.

Comment: i added my xml layout file

Comment: You shouldn't remove `ListView`. Leave the `ListView` as it was before. Create a new layout file named `item_row`, and put there the code from the answer, nothing more. Then when instantiating your adapter point out your newly created layout: `new ArrayAdapter<Special>(this, R.layout.item_row, specials);`

Comment: Perfect! It is spacing as intended now. Thank you ver ymcuh!